# Which of the following statement(s) is(are) equivalent to saying that $LUB(A) ≤ LUB(B)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be non-empty subsets of real numbers.

Which of the following statement(s)
is(are) equivalent to saying that $LUB(A) ≤ LUB(B)$?

$(a)$ For every $a ∈ A$ and $\epsilon  > 0$ there exists $a,b ∈ B $ such that $a < b + \epsilon.$

$(b)$ For every $b ∈ B$ there exists an $a ∈ A$ such that $a ≤ b.$

$(c)$ There exists $b ∈ B$ such that $a ≤ b$ for all $a ∈ A.$

$(d)$ There exists $a ∈ A$ such that $a ≤ b$ for all $b ∈ B.$

i take $x_n= \frac{1}{2n} \in  A$  and  $y_n= \frac{1}{n}\in
 B$, now  $LUB(A) ≤ LUB(B)$..after that im not able to proceed further
...

Any hints/solution

thanks u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) is true and I will let you prove it by using the definition of lub. I will give counterexamples for b),c) and d). Take $A=[0,2], B=[0,1]$. You get a counterexample for b) and d ). Take $A=[0,1], B=[0,1)$ for c).

Comment: Regarding counterexample for part b, lub of A is 2 which is greater than lub of B which is 1. It does not satisfy the conditions given in the question.

Comment: The question is whether the conditions are equivalent to $lub A \leq lub B$. You have to look at both implications; in the case of b) the condition there is satisfied but it is not true that  $lub A \leq lub B$. So b) is not equivalent to $lub A \leq lub B$.

Comment: @kavi Rama guruji. Thanks u